# send and recv C++

Tags: c++, sockets

im trying to use send and recv commands in my program which is a client server messaging software.

however it seems that when the code is running i cannot pass message because send cmd is not passing the data. after the command is executed the data i try to pass (buffer) is empty, i checked by printing (buffer). Why could this be....i would be grateful if anyone can help me.

**Server side code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int client, server, i;
    int portNum = 1500;
    bool isExit = false;
    int bufsize = 1024;
    char buffer[bufsize];

struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    socklen_t size;

// init socket

    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (client < 0)
    {
    cout << "Error establishing connection" << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Server Socket connection created..." << endl;

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  //  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.5");
// Binding socket  

    if (bind(client, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
    cout << "Error binding socket...." << endl; 
    exit(1);
    }

size = sizeof(server_addr);
cout << "Looking for clients..." << endl;

// Listening socket

    listen(client, 1);

// Accept client

    server = accept(client, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, &size);
if (server < 0)
{
cout << "Error on accepting.." << endl;
exit(1);
}
 cout << "Connected with client..." << endl;
cout << "Enter your message:\n" << endl;
    cin >> buffer;
    cout << buffer;
    send(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
cout << "message sent...\n", buffer;
return 0;
}
```

**client side code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int client, server, i;
    int portNum = 1500;
    bool isExit = false;
    int bufsize = 1024;
    char buffer[bufsize];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

// Init socket 


    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (client < 0)
    {
    cout << "Error creating socket" << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

cout << "Client socket created" << endl;

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.5");
// Connecting socket server

if (connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == 0)

{
     cout << "Connecting to server..." << endl;
     recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);

     buffer[bufsize] = '\0';

     cout << "client: received", buffer;

 close(client);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, there is also one other bug in your code. Your code assumes that `send`() will always send the number of bytes given in its fourth parameter. This is a common programming bug, because this is not true. send() may send fewer bytes than what was requested. You must check the return value from send(), and decide what to do accordingly. See the send(2) manual page for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually printing `buffer` :

```
cout << "client: received", buffer;
```

should be :

```
cout << "client: received " << buffer;
```

You probably also want an `endl` :

```
cout << "client: received " << buffer << endl;
```

Comment: Don't use `endl` unless you have to flush the buffer. "\n" is suitable in most of scenarios.